# Getting IO error and Attribute error when running example.py

Tags: chirp

I am getting IO error because ~/.chirprc file is not found. The entire chirp sdk is downloaded from the official https://developers.chirp.io/downloads.

Also there is a Attribute error which seems to be getting ignored

1. Ran the following commands:

   ```
   python setup.py install
   python setup.py build
   python example.py
   ```
2. Exact error is:

   ```
   python example.py
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "example.py", line 102, in <module>
       main(args.c, args.i, args.o, args.b, args.s)
     File "example.py", line 56, in main
       sdk = ChirpConnect(block=block_name)
     File "C:\00_Work\01_Documents\09_Papers\05_Chirp\chirpsdk\connect.py", 
   line 392, in __init__
       self.read_chirprc(block)
     File "C:\00_Work\01_Documents\09_Papers\05_Chirp\chirpsdk\connect.py", 
   line 485, in read_chirprc
       raise IOError('Could not find a ~/.chirprc file')
   IOError: Could not find a ~/.chirprc file
   Exception AttributeError: "'ChirpConnect' object has no attribute '_sdk'" 
   in <bound method ChirpConnect.__del__ of <chirpsdk.connect.ChirpConnect 
   object at 0x0000000006CE4278>> ignored
   ```

Comment: After further debugging, this issue was solved. We have to save a _'.chirprc'_ file at _'C:\Users\<username>\'_ location.

A _'.chirprc'_ file is a config file that gets used by the application. Contents of this file can be copied from this [https://developers.chirp.io/applications](https://developers.chirp.io/applications) link. Just select PYTHON, copy the config data and paste it in the _'.chirprc'_ file.

Comment: Adding to previous comment:

I have named the _'.chirprc'_ file as _'a.chirprc'_ file. As windows understands the _'.chirprc'_ as a extension. Had to rename it in _example.py_ file and _connect.py_ file.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else landing on this page, documentation for the Python SDK can be found at https://developers.chirp.io/docs/getting-started/python.

The `~/.chirprc` file works for me on Windows. You must be sure to save it in the same place as this path as output by Python.

```
import os
os.path.expanduser('~/.chirprc')
```